# Magento 2: Override protected function getBackUrl in Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart.php

Tags: magento2

I just want to override below method but its not working anymore.
Magento 2: Override `protected function getBackUrl` From `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart.php`

Any idea please share 
My php code is :

```
<?php

namespace Dynamic\Checkout\Controller\Magento\Checkout;

use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View\ViewInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;

class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart
{
    protected function getBackUrl($defaultUrl = null)
        {
        echo "8888 ";exit;
    }   
}
```

and di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart" type="Dynamic\Checkout\Controller\Magento\Checkout\Cart" />
</config>
```

Comment: Can you post your code lines here?

Comment: i updated my ans..

Comment: Try to move `di.xml` to under `etc/frontend/di.xml`.

Comment: and execute `di:compile` command @Camit1dk